# How to convert a minimum spanning tree to a path/route in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a minimum spanning tree in Java.
This is in a `Graph` class which has a list of `Node`s, those `Node` classes have a list of `Edge` classes which have a boolean if they are in the MST or not.
Example:
[image]
In this example a human can see that a path/route to go to all the places and back from the start is: (Start-A --> A-Start --> Start-B --> B-C --> C-B --> B-D --> D-B --> B-Start), how can I code this route to a String, only knowing which connections to use and the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved using DFS for trees.
It could be useful to look at the tree by using `Start` as a root.
Imagine that from node `Start` we go to node `A`. We add this movement to our `path` string. Now two possibilities can materialize: the first is that `A` has no child, so we go back to `Start` and we have to print the inverse of the movement done before; the second is that `A` has one or more children, in which case we do a movement to reach the first child (update the string). When we have finished exploring the "depth" of this child we'll go back to `A` and start with another child (if it's present).

Probably, it's more difficult to explain this in words than seeing this in code: the **key concept** here is that when we finish exploring the depth of a possible path we have to get back to the node from which it started (which corresponds only to adding the inverse of the movement string in the parent).

```java
public void dfs(Node u, Node previous, StringBuilder path) {
        for(Edge e: u.edges) {
            // an edge is a pair (e.a, e.b)
            if(!e.mst || e.b.equals(previous)) {
                continue;
            }
            path.append(u + "->" + e.b + "\n");
            dfs(e.b, u, path);
            path.append(e.b + "->" + u + "\n"); // after exploring a child we must get back
        }
    }
```

This is the code example that you can adapt to your use case.

Comment: Dfs=Depth first search

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed, got it working now!